# Is Malick's Tree of Life a “too masculine” movie?

Tags: analysis, reception, the-tree-of-life

It's not a secret that all of Malick's movies revolve around male characters. Nevertheless, I was a bit impressed when checking [this infography](http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20160802-100-greatest-films-of-the-21st-century-infographic) about how a set of critics commissioned by the BBC voted to make *Tree of Life* the 7th best movie of the 21st century. Go to the “Films by Gender” section and you will easily realize that *Tree of Life* has the largest disparate female to male ratio in the voting tally, to the point that there is no doubt the movie makes it so high in the list thanks to the support of male critics compared to the rest of movies in the top ten, which have a more or less even support by both sexes (despite the fact there are way less female critics overall).

This is a trend I have long suspected myself: female moviegoers do not strongly relate to the plot, narrative, style or insight of *Tree of Life*. Most of my female friends price Malick's stunning visuals and understand “what-is-happening”, but barely connect to the movie. On the contrary, male friends, some of them even casual moviegoers, people who customarily complain about the movie's pace and style, still recognize themselves in it and come out of the screening citing this or that childhood memory or what their parents meant for them.

I would like to read a more informed opinion on the matter. Is *Tree of Life* “too masculine”? Is this just my impression? What factors make women not to relate to the movie as strongly as men?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83547/discussion-on-question-by-je-b-is-malicks-tree-of-life-a-too-masculine-movie).